# Operator precedence - Arithmetic and Conditional operators

Tags: java, operator-precedence

I want to understand why the following code throws *Null pointer exception*.

```
import java.util.List;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = null;
        System.out.println("Result is: " + names == null ? null : names.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you want names == null ? `0` : names.size()

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue is that your print statement is evaluated as:

```
System.out.println(("Result is: " + names) == null ? null : names.size());
```

This is due to the fact that [`+` has more precedence than `?:` operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) So, as the string - *"Result is null"* is not equal to `null`, evaluating `names.size()` throws NPE.

Note that, when `null` is used in string concatenation, it is automatically converted to `"null"`. So, `"Result is: " + null` will not throw `NPE`. This is as per [JLS - String Conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11):

> If the reference is `null`, it is converted to the string `"null"` (four ASCII characters n, u, l, l).

To fix the issue, you should add parenthesis around your conditional expression to enforce greater precendence to it:

```
System.out.println("Result is: " + (names == null ? null : names.size()));
```

Answer (score 4):

Correcting Jigar's answer, this actually *works*:

```
someString + null
```

To fix OP's code, just add parenthesis - in this way the operations will be performed in the correct order and the result will be as expected:

```
System.out.println("Result is: " + (names == null ? null : names.size()));
```

Answer (score 2):

you are writing **"Result is: " + names** which is not equivalent to **null** so its trying to print `names.size()`. But when `names.size()` is called it throw null pointer exception as names is still null.

Modify

```
System.out.println("Result is: " + names == null ? null : names.size());
```

to

```
System.out.print("Result is: ");
System.out.println( names == null ? null : names.size());
```

then you will get null as output.